# How to send data while navigating another page without uri query

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, navigation

Basically I have a longlistselector and it contains writings when one of them is selected I am going to navigate to a page and its going to show the all detailed information of this writing (article , date , image etc.)

Don't worry about the data, I checked and data contains the details all I need is how to send this Writing object (named data) with navigating.Or can you give any suggestion how can I do this but without using uri query

Thank you

```
    private void longList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        LongListSelector selector = sender as LongListSelector;
        Writing data = selector.SelectedItem as Writing;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/WritingPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));     
    }
```

Comment: use ajax. it will allow you to show the data on the current page without having to navigate to it

Comment: Why don't you want to add the Writing ID to the URI to identify what to open on the target page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass an Object from one page to another PhoneApplicationservice is easiest way. Here is the simple example to pass Object from one page to another. Its tested.

```
private void longList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.ContainsKey("Data"))
          if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Data"] != null)
               PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Remove("Data");
         LongListSelector selector = sender as LongListSelector;
         Writing data = selector.SelectedItem as Writing;
         PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Data"] = data ;
         NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/WritingPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));     
    }


//On second page
//I assume you want to Data on page load
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
      Writing data = new Writing ();
     data =(Writing)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Data"]
     PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Remove("Data");    
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer  , also i have a question ,what about after we take the object from phoeapplicationservice is it going to be deleted ? if not its scaring to expand the phone memory everytime i click the article

Answer (score 0):

Are you coding in MVVM ?
If yes, you can send and register to an Event (published by your ViewModel linked to the LongList and subscribe this event in your ViewModel linked to WrittingPage.)

Answer (score 0):

Simple and better way is to make "Writing" object scope Global. 
Here, I added a class file to solution "Global.cs" and I declared "data" variable of "Writing" type.

```
public static Writing data = new Writing();
```

Use the same code you did and access the "data" variable here. I have done some minor change to your code.

```
private void longList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    LongListSelector selector = sender as LongListSelector;
    Global.data = selector.SelectedItem as Writing;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/WritingPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));     
}
```

Now access "data" variable on "WritingPage.xaml" after you navigate to it. Use value of this variable and then make it null.